# Spring MVC autocomplete jquery dropdown doesnt shown

Tags: jquery, spring, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

Hello guys i follow a tutorial for autocomplete in an input field but i have a problem. The problem is that everything is ok, but the dropdown list doesn't show.

Here is my jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*"%>


<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Καταχώρηση Εγγράφου</title>



 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

 <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js">    </script>


  <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {

   $( "#apostoleas" ).autocomplete({


        source: '${pageContext. request. contextPath}/articles/get_country_list.html'

});

});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

<body>

<h1 align="left"><font size="5"> &nbsp;<spring:message  code="label.eggrafo" /></font></h1>



<c:url var="saveArticleUrl" value="/articles/saveeggrafo.html" />
<form:form   name="sds"  enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm()"  modelAttribute="eggrafo" method="POST" action="${saveArticleUrl}">
<table style=" min-height:570px; height:570px;min-width:570px; width:570px;  " bgcolor="990099">
     <tr>
        <th style="display:none">Id</th>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <th style="display:none"><form:input readonly="true" path="idtypiko" /></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <th style="display:none">User</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
         <th style="display:none"><form:input  path="username" value="${username}" /></th>    
    </tr> 

     <tr>
        <th><FONT SIZE="5" FACE="courier" ><spring:message   code="label.etos" /></FONT></th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><form:input cssStyle="width: 420px;height: 30px;font-size : 1.0em;"   id="etos" path="year" value="${year}"/></th>

    </tr>
     <tr>
        <th><FONT SIZE="5" FACE="courier" ><spring:message code="label.fakelos" /></FONT></th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
     <th><form:input cssStyle="width: 420px;height: 30px;font-size : 1.0em;" path="fakelos_eggrafou" id="fakelos_eggrafou" /></th>

    <%--<th><form:select  class="styled-select"   path="fakelos_eggrafou" >
                <OPTION  onclick="javascript:mine();"   selected="selected" VALUE=""><c:out value="Άλλο"/></OPTION>
                <c:forEach items="${fakeloi}" var="fake">
                <OPTION   onclick="javascript:form();" VALUE="${fake}"><c:out value="${fake}"/></OPTION>
                </c:forEach>
                </form:select></th> --%>    
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <th><FONT SIZE="5" FACE="courier" ><spring:message code="label.diab" /></FONT></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
         <th><form:select  class="styled-select"  path="diabathmisi">
                <c:forEach items="${diabathmiseis}" var="diab">
                <OPTION VALUE="${diab.onoma}"><c:out value="${diab.onoma}"/></OPTION>
                </c:forEach>
                </form:select></th>

    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <th><FONT SIZE="5" FACE="courier" ><spring:message code="label.apostol" /></FONT></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
    <%-- <th>
       <form:select  id="apostoleas" class="styled-select1"  path="apostoleas">
                <c:forEach items="${apostoleis}" var="apost">
                <OPTION VALUE="${apost.apostoleas}"><c:out value="${apost.apostoleas}"/></OPTION>
                </c:forEach>
                </form:select>

                </th>  --%>
<td><form:input   id="apostoleas"  path="apostoleas"   /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><FONT SIZE="5" FACE="courier" ><spring:message code="label.tauteg" /></FONT></th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><form:input cssStyle="width: 420px;height: 30px;font-size : 1.0em;"  id="tautotitaegg"  path="tautotitaeg"   /></th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th><FONT SIZE="5" FACE="courier" ><spring:message code="label.thema" /></FONT></th>    
</tr>
<tr>
    <th><form:input cssStyle="width: 420px;height: 30px;font-size : 1.0em;" path="thema" /></th>
</tr>

<tr>
     <th><FONT SIZE="5" FACE="courier" ><spring:message code="label.sinimena" /></FONT></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th><form:input cssStyle="width: 420px;height: 30px;font-size : 1.0em;" path="sinimena" /></th>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <th><FONT SIZE="5" FACE="courier" ><spring:message code="label.hmerypogr" /></FONT></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <th> <input style="width: 420px;height: 30px;font-size : 1.0em;"  value="${date}" name="hmeromhniaypog" id="datepick" class="date-pick"/>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        datepickr('datepick', { dateFormat: 'Y-m-d' });
                    </script></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th><FONT SIZE="5" FACE="courier" >Αρχείο</FONT></th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><form:input cssStyle="width: 420px;height: 30px;font-size : 1.0em;" path="file" type="file" id="file"/></th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th><FONT SIZE="5" FACE="courier" ><spring:message code="label.parat" /></FONT></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th><form:textarea cssStyle="width: 420px;height: 30px;font-size : 1.0em;" cols="30" rows="3" path="parathrhseis" /></th>
</tr>
    <tr>


    </table>
    <br />
<input  name="s" class="groovybutton" onMouseOver="goLite(this.form.name,this.name)" onMouseOut="goDim(this.form.name,this.name)" type="submit" value="<spring:message code="label.button" />" />






</form:form>


     </body>
```

And here is the controller part:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get_country_list",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        headers="Accept=*/*")
public @ResponseBody List<String> getCountryList(@RequestParam("term") String query) {

     List<String> countries;

    String data = "Afghanistan, Albania, Algeria, Andorra, Angola, Antigua & Deps,"+ 
            "Argentina, Armenia, Australia, Austria,Azerbaijan,Bahamas,Bahrain,Bangladesh,Barbados,"+ 
            "Belarus,Belgium,Belize,Benin,Bhutan,Bolivia,Bosnia Herzegovina,Botswana,Brazil,Brunei,"+ 
            "Bulgaria,Burkina,Burundi,Cambodia,Cameroon,Canada,Cape Verde,Central African Rep,Chad,"+ 
            "Chile,China,Colombia,Comoros,Congo,Congo {Democratic Rep},Costa Rica,Croatia,Cuba,Cyprus,"+ 
            "Czech Republic,Denmark,Djibouti,Dominica,Dominican Republic,East Timor,Ecuador,Egypt,El Salvador,"+ 
            "Equatorial Guinea, Eritrea,Estonia,Ethiopia,Fiji,Finland,France,Gabon,Gambia,Georgia,Germany,"+ 
            "Ghana, Greece, Grenada,Guatemala,Guinea,Guinea-Bissau,Guyana,Haiti,Honduras,Hungary,Iceland,"+ 
            "India, Indonesia,Iran,Iraq,Ireland {Republic},Israel,Italy,Ivory Coast,Jamaica,Japan,"+ 
            "Jordan,Kazakhstan,Kenya,Kiribati,Korea North,Korea South,Kosovo,Kuwait,Kyrgyzstan,Laos,"+ 
            "Latvia,Lebanon,Lesotho,Liberia,Libya,Liechtenstein,Lithuania,Luxembourg,Macedonia,Madagascar,"+ 
            "Malawi,Malaysia,Maldives,Mali,Malta,Marshall Islands,Mauritania,Mauritius,Mexico,Micronesia,"+ 
            "Moldova,Monaco,Mongolia,Montenegro,Morocco,Mozambique,Myanmar {Burma},Namibia,Nauru,Nepal,"+ 
            "Netherlands,New Zealand,Nicaragua,Niger,Nigeria,Norway,Oman,Pakistan,Palau,Panama,Papua New Guinea,"+ 
            "Paraguay,Peru,Philippines,Poland,Portugal,Qatar,Romania,Russian Federation,Rwanda,St Kitts & Nevis,"+
            "St Lucia,Saint Vincent & the Grenadines,Samoa,San Marino,Sao Tome & Principe,Saudi Arabia,Senegal,"+ 
            "Serbia,Seychelles,Sierra Leone,Singapore,Slovakia,Slovenia,Solomon Islands,Somalia,South Africa,"+ 
            "Spain,Sri Lanka,Sudan,Suriname,Swaziland,Sweden,Switzerland,Syria,Taiwan,Tajikistan,Tanzania, "+
            "Thailand,Togo,Tonga,Trinidad & Tobago,Tunisia,Turkey,Turkmenistan,Tuvalu,Uganda,Ukraine,United Arab Emirates,"+
            "United Kingdom,United States,Uruguay,Uzbekistan,Vanuatu,Vatican City,Venezuela,Vietnam,Yemen,Zambia,Zimbabwe";

    countries = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(data, ",");

    //Parse the country CSV list and set as Array
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        countries.add(st.nextToken().trim());
    }


    String country = null;
    query = query.toLowerCase();
    List<String> matched = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0; i < countries.size(); i++) {
        country = countries.get(i).toLowerCase();
        if(country.startsWith(query)) {
            matched.add(countries.get(i));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(matched);
    return matched;
}
```

Does anybody know where is the problem guys?

I follow this tutorial 
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-autocomplete-json-tutorial/

Also i check what firebug return and returns the following:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/Spring3Hibernate/articles/get_country_list.html?term=5
```

406 Not Acceptable
        66ms

The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.

Comment: Is server side request coming for getting the name ?

Comment: yes, the following line of code System.out.println(matched); prints me the list that it passes to jsp

Answer (score 2):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getProductAutoCompleteList.do", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=*/*")
    public @ResponseBody List<String> getProductAutoComplete(@RequestParam("term") String prodName, HttpServletResponse response){
        logger.info("getProductAutoCompleteList called with parameter: " + prodName);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        final List<String> productList = ProductSearchHelper.getProductAutoCompleteList(prodName);


        response.setContentType("application/json");
        return productList;
    }
```

Make sure you

1. specify response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK); in controller method
2. optional, setContentType as application/json
3. having @ResponseBody annotation, Spring MVC invokes a MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter built on the Jackson JSON processor. This implementation is enabled automatically when you use the mvc:annotation-driven configuration element with Jackson present in your classpath.